# Reset icon of the last clicked view upon clicking a view in GridLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-gridview

I am developing a music playing app but I've been stuck with fixing a bug for the last two days. [Here is a screenshot of the app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgPQK.png) Basically the user can add a new view, name it however he wishes and choose a mp3 file to link to that view.

As you can see Every view has a text that a little play icon. This icon switches to a pause icon while the audio is playing. [Here you can see the pause icon.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPjGA.png)

**Issue 1:**
When the user starts a sound and then click on another square, the previous sound stops as it should and the new sound begins, but the old square's icon stays the pause icon, and so on the screen eventally many squares will have the pause icon while not actually playing sound.

**Issue 2:** Let's say that the user clicks the absolute first square, which in the arrayList corresponds to position 0. Then the user scrolls down to the point that the square he clicked is no longer visible. When the user scrolls up again the square he clicked on will have the play icon set, while playing sound. I figured that's because in my GridAdapter i set every newly recicled view to have the play icon and I can't figure out how to set an if statement. How should the adapter know wether the box is playing a sound?

Many thanks and love.

GridItemAdapter.java:

```
public class GridItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GridItem> {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = GridItemAdapter.class.getSimpleName();


    public GridItemAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<GridItem> gridItems) {
        // Here, we initialize the ArrayAdapter's internal storage for the context and the list.
        // the second argument is used when the ArrayAdapter is populating a single TextView.
        // Because this is a custom adapter for two TextViews and an ImageView, the adapter is not
        // going to use this second argument, so it can be any value. Here, we used 0.
        super(context, 0, gridItems);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View gridItemView = convertView;
        if(gridItemView == null) {
            gridItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
        }

        // Get the {@link AndroidFlavor} object located at this position in the list
        GridItem currentGridItem = getItem(position);

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_name
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) gridItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
        // set this text on the name TextView
        nameTextView.setText(currentGridItem.getSoundName());

        ImageView playIcon = (ImageView) gridItemView.findViewById(R.id.image_1);

        playIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_ic);




        // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews and an ImageView)
        // so that it can be shown in the ListView
        return gridItemView;
    }

}
```

- MainActivity.java snippets of interest :

  ```
  gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

              /*
              if (lastPosition != -1) {
                  Log.v(TAG3, "Inisde if block, lastposition = " + lastPosition);
                  // Whatever position you're looking for
                  int firstPosition = gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                  int wantedChild = lastPosition - firstPosition;
                  View wantedView = gridView.getChildAt(wantedChild);

                  Log.v(TAG3, "lastRow initiated, lastrow = " + wantedView);
                  ImageView lastIc = (ImageView) wantedView.findViewById(R.id.image_1);
                  lastIc.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_ic);

              }
              */

              togglePlayback(i, view);
              lastPosition = i;
              Log.v(TAG3, "outside if block, lastPosition = " + lastPosition);
          }
      });

  public void togglePlayback(int i, View v){
      final View view = v;

      if(!isPlaying) {
          releaseMediaPlayer();

          ImageView playIc = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_1);
          playIc.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_ic);
          GridItem word = gridItems.get(i);


          try {
              mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse(word.getSoundPath()));
          }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          mMediaPlayer.start();
          isPlaying = true;

          mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
              @Override
              public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                  releaseMediaPlayer();
                  ImageView playIc = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_1);
                  playIc.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_ic);
                  isPlaying = false;
              }
          });
      }else{
          releaseMediaPlayer();
          ImageView playIc = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_1);
          playIc.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_ic);
          isPlaying = false;
      }



  }
  ```

Comment: Don't link your code to an external site. We don't need all of the lines just the troublesome ones. Add a minimal verifiable example.

Comment: Ok I'll add the code in the post

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to achieve it(I have not gone through your code since the snippet was not provided yet, the variables used below are self-explanatory):

1. First add a flag say `isPlaying` in the model class of an item in gridview
2. Now in getView method, add below code

   `if(itemList.get(index).isPlaying) {
      //set the icon to pause one
   } else {
      //set the icon to playing one
   }`
3. Now, in view's click listener, add this

   `if(itemList.get(index).isPlaying) {
      // write the code to pause the current song
   } else {
      // pause your <previousIndex> song
      // play <index> item
      itemList.get(index).isPlaying = true;
      itemList.get(previousIndex).isPlaying = false;
      previousIndex = index;
      notifyDataSetChanged();
   }`

I have just written the basic logic, you need to write your code regarding playing/pause of your songs.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your entry I will begin looking into it now. Do you mind me asking what is a flag? I haven't heard of them yet, I'm a newbie.

Comment: Actually thanks to you I managed to solve issue 2 but not issue 1. Also now some blocks in the grid are not clickable.

Comment: A flag is basically a variable , (preferably Boolean, though it can be an int or anything) to validate a pass/fail scenario or signify something, like in our case `isPlaying` variable/flag signifies that the current item is playing if its value is true and false otherwise. Similarly, you could have taken the isPlaying as an int also, say if its Zero then its not playing and if 1, then its playing. Hope you get it.

Comment: Check to make sure that you have put click listener code outside of any if-else block. If not, then it is the reason why some views will not be clickable.

Comment: The onItemClickListener is inside onCreate. Also why after copying you exact code I can't call notifyDataSetChanged()? Since I can't use it it doesn't refresh the views i think and that's why now the icon doesn't change at all.

Comment: ok I called gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and now it changes icon but playback is not working properly: it does not start at all on some items, or it chenges to the wrong icon, or it doesn't stop at all. I'm going mad. Here is mainActivity. http://pastebin.com/naFLYZif